# pymongo update multiple fields in a document only if one field value is greater than the current

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Using pymongo, I only want to update certain fields of a document if a specific field is greater.
for example, the original document could look something like this for an auction application

```json
{
    "_id": ".....",
    "highestbid": 100,
    "highestbidder": "joe",
    "someotherinfo": "...."
}
```

suppose now a bidder named john outbid joe at 200. How could I use collection.update() to update both the highestbid field and highestbidder field only if the new bid is higher than highestbid, while leaving someotherinfo alone?

I know I can use $max to insert the higher of the two bid values, but I'm not sure how to update highestbidder depending on the result of highestbid all in a single .update(), if it is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the operator `$lt` to verify that old bid is less then the new one to update your document, this should solve your problem:

```js
db.collection.update({
    "highestbid": {
        "$lt": 200
    }
}, {
    "$set": {
        "highestbid": 200,
        "highestbidder": "jhon"
    }
}, {
    "multi": false
})
```

Using `pymongo`:

```py
db.collection.update_one({
    "highestbid": {
        "$lt": 200
    }
}, {
    "$set": {
        "highestbid": 200,
        "highestbidder": "jhon"
    }
})
```

Comment: Im getting "upsert must be true or false" but if i add upsert = False, it complains that there are too many arguments

Comment: I also forgot to tag this but im using django